# Propensity score matching after imputation in R with mice

Tags: r, data-imputation, propensity-scores

9I have a dataset (500 rows) with missing values in different variables for a propensity score analysis. First I created the propensity score matching by omitting the rows with missing values (about 100 rows) in the variables I used for propensity score calculation, but now I would like to try to impute the missing values with the mice package.

In a first step I imputed the data like this:

```
impute <- mice(mydata, method = 
  methods, predictorMatrix = 
  predictormatrix, m = 5, maxit = 
   3)
mydata <- complete(impute)
```

So - as far as I understand - "mydata" now is a new data frame with the imputed values, but it is the first out of 5 different attempts of imputation (because the first attempt is used by default).

Now, as "mydata" is a data frame, I have my "full" data available and can continue with my propensity score matching code:

```
# matching
match <- matchit(treatment ~ independent1 + independet2 + independent3, data = mydata, method = "nearest")
matched_data <- match.data(match)

# model for outcome by treatment
model <- glm(outcome ~ treatment, data = matched_data, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
publish(model)
```

So this obviously works if I'm fine with using only the first out of 5 possible imputed datasets (as far as I now "complete" uses the first dataset by default).

Now my question is: I read about the "pool" function, but it seems that in the end I need a regression formula (like seen here https://rdrr.io/cran/mice/man/pool.html at the end of the page > "Example").
**My favorite result of the imputed data would be a completed dataset** with the **same number of rows** as before the imputation process (5oo rows) but with imputed values (by all 5 datasets) instead of NAs.

For example:

```
final_imputed_data <- complete(impute) # don't use the first imputed dataset (out of 5) but all 5
```

Or do I misunderstand the sense of multiple imputation?

Comment: Is the end goal of this analysis to estimate the propensity scores, or are you going to use the propensity scores as one step in a further analysis?

Comment: After propensity score matching I would like to do further analyses with the matched dataset...

Answer (score 2):

To do multiple imputation with propensity score matching, you should use the `MatchThem` package, which was designed specifically for this purpose. You need to do the following steps:

1. Multiply impute the data, creating M (e.g., 5) separate datasets with the missing values filled in by estimates of the missing values. `mice` does this and stores the output in a `mids` object (which you have called `impute`). You should use way more than 5 (e.g., 50) imputations, as more is always better.
2. Estimate propensity scores within each imputed dataset and then perform the matching within each imputed dataset. `MatchThem` does this using the `matchthem()` function, which uses the same sytnax as `matchit()` but takes in a `mids` object instead of a data frame.
3. Assess balance on the matched multiply imputed data. The `cobalt` package works with `matchthem` objects (called `mimids` objects) to assess balance across and within imputed datasets.
4. If balance is achieved, estimate the effect within the imputed datasets. The `MatchThem` functions `with()` and `pool()` (which work similarly to the corresponding functions in `mice`) do this, correctly incorporating the weights, matching structure, and correction for multiple imputation.

All this is described in the `MatchThem` [paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2021/RJ-2021-073/index.html) and documentation. Remember that propensity score matching and multiple imputation are advanced statistical techniques and should only be used by someone with advanced statistical training using these methods.

Comment: What about the problem made you want to use propensity scores?  And why use a matching algorithm that discards valid data?

Comment: Hi Noah, thank you for your answer! I read the MatchThem paper you linked here, but I've still got the question, if there is a possibility, to get back a data frame after multiple imputation for further analyses similar to the match.data function, which gives back a full data frame after using matchit().

Comment: Use the `complete()` function in `MatchThem`.

Comment: Hi Noah, thank you again for your response. Could you maybe help me with a code snippet, how to create a "cross section dataset"? If I use complete() with default parameters the FIRST dataset of the 5 will be selected. Is there a way to create a cross section of the different datasets? Does that make sense?

Comment: I mean, I have 5 different datasets - how do I decide, which of them to use for my subsequent analyses?

Comment: You have to perform the same analysis in all of them and then combine the results using formulas commonly referred to as "Rubin's Rules", which are implemented in `mice::pool()` and `MatchThem::pool()`. Read the documentation for `complete()`; you will see ways to extract more than one dataset.

Comment: Hi Noah! Thanks for your help! Do you mean this documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyft/versions/0.4.5/topics/complete ? Or the "complete" section in this document: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchThem/MatchThem.pdf (page 3) ?

Comment: The latter (`?MatchThem::complete`). You should always read a function's documentation if the default arguments aren't doing what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129623/discussion-between-mdstat-and-noah).